# use topology.name instead of storm.id in apache storm log4j2 config

Tags: log4j2, apache-storm

in apache storm, the workers-artifacts logs are created for different topologies with the storm id (topology name + unique id). this makes it difficult to find the latest logs. so, instead of storm.id, how can we use the config topology.name?
worker.xml config:
i would like to use something like

```
fileName="${sys:workers.artifacts}/${sys:topology.name}/${sys:logfile.name}"
```

instead of the default

```
fileName="${sys:workers.artifacts}/${sys:storm.id}/${sys:worker.port}/${sys:logfile.name}"
```

i did try this, however, the log dir created is like this parameter is undefined:

```
# ls
${sys:topology.name}
```

can anyone help?

Comment: Are you running storm in local or remote mode? and are you sure that the variable topology.name is really set?

Comment: i'm running storm in a remote mode - nimus and ui in one node, supervisors and topologies in 2 other nodes. and i'm able to see the topology.name under Topology Configuration in nimbus ui. doesn't that mean the property is set?

Comment: I faced a similar problem as well. It looks like the that the supervisors do not know that configuration. I would recommend to print all sys variables in a supervisor/bolt, then you can see, if the variable is really set there.

Comment: oh i see. sure, let me try that

Comment: Could you resolve that?

Comment: yes and no :D I couldn't get the value of topology.name in log4j config. instead, I used the storm-logviewer which served my purpose. with logviewer, I was able to keep the logs of only the running topologies. it cleared the old logs (that of dead topologies) and that solved the confusion of multiple log directories. also, now I'm able to see the logs from storm UI, which is an added advantage.